# how should i trigger a click of img tag inside a ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="product_parts">
                    <ul id="product_list">
                      <li class="active" data-maxlength="200" > <img src="images/ts/1.jpg" /> </li>
                      <li data-maxlength="200" > <img src="images/ts/2.jpg" /> </li>
                      <li data-maxlength="60" > <img src="images/ts/3.jpg" /> </li>
                      <li data-maxlength="60" > <img src="images/ts/1.jpg" /> </li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is an unordered list. i have a function that runs when the img tag of a list is clicked.Now i want this myfunction() to run for every img list item.
This is my funnction

```
$('#product_parts li>img').click(function(){
    $('#product_parts li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
    var selected_canvas_image = $(this).attr('src');

    var obj = 'main_layer_'+($(this).parents('li').index() + 1) ;

    add_canvas(false,selected_canvas_image,'','all',obj);

})
```

This was the solution i tried

```
var lis = document.getElementById("product_list").getElementsByTagName('li').find('li);
for(i=0;i<lis.length();i++)
{
lis[i].click();
}
```

Unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: Is there a reason you are using vanilla javascript to get the lis and click each one? You already used jQuery to write the function.

Comment: `.length` isn't a function, it's a property. `lis.length()` should be `lis.length`

Comment: The code you tried is calling .click() on the li elements, not the img elements. Also, clickable images is an accessibility fail: how do keyboard-only users navigate on your page?

Comment: `$('#product_parts li>img').click();` Is that what you are looking for? Because reading 3 times question, i'm still not sure what you are expecting?!...  I'm not sure why would you want to trigger click **for all** these images at once?

Comment: @Dudebird47 No i may use jquery also all i want is a solution.

Comment: @A.Wolff I want the list image to be clicked so that canvas renders the objects for different list items and and i can download whatever is there on the canvas.

Comment: I am not sure either about what you are trying to do.... But as said before, you are using var lis = document.getElementById("product_list").getElementsByTagName('li');  instead of var lis = document.getElementById("product_list").getElementsByTagName('img');

Comment: $('#product_parts li>img').click, this line is already applying event on img tag, what else u need ?

Comment: @RachitBhargava Well, sounds like a XY problem but like said then it should work: `$('#product_parts li>img').click();`

Comment: @AvinashAgrawal i want to initiate a forced click to every list item through javascript

Comment: @RachitBhargava u can use jquery.each method on the ul...

Answer (score 2):

In your Vanilla JavaScript, there is several problems.

One, you have a syntax error: `for(i=0;i<lis.length();i++)`

`length` isn't a function, but you are using it as one. It should be `lis.length` instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].click();
}
```

Two, you are triggering a click event on `#product_list li`, not the `img`:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("product_list").getElementsByTagName('li');
```

You should select the `img` instead of the `li`:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("product_list").getElementsByTagName('img');
```

If you are fine with [losing a little bit of browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector), you can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#product_list li>img");
```

Your code should now look like:

```
var lis = document.querySelectorAll("#product_list li>img");
for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].click();
}
```

### However

You are already using jQuery in you project, so you might as well use it's functions:

```
$("#product_list li>img").click()
```

Much shorter, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Jquery already here is a simple solution

```
$( "#product_parts li>img" ).each( function( index, element ){
   $(element).click();
});
```

Just iterate over each of the image in list and click them.

Here is a working JS Fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g838s4zd/2/

Comment: Why use `.each()` to iterate manually, instead of the equivalent `$("#product_parts img").click()`?

Comment: I just used a $.each in case you might want to do something to a particular image while iterating . Just something closer to the for loop the OP wanted.As the other answer gave .click() in their answer.